# Question regarding a subset E open relative to some subset Y of metric space X

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $Y\subset X$. A subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if $E=Y\cap G$ for some open subset G of X.

I have trouble understanding some parts of the theorem. I'd like to know that if $E$ is open relative to $Y$, will my $E$ be an open sphere around the boundary of $Y$? Am I thinking it in a correct way? And, so if it is a sphere (open) around the boundary, then what about interior points of $E$? Or will a sphere of larger radius do the job? [image]

Comment: An open set need not be an open sphere, but can be a union of spheres in general. And boundary of $Y$ where? In $Y$ itself $Y$ has no boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand theorem graphically. Your outer box is $(X,d)$ space and inner box is $(Y,d)$ space and $E$ is a subset of $Y$. So make another box for $E$ inside $Y$ and $G$ which is open in $X$ may or may not be completely in $Y$ but always intersects $Y$ and yields $E$ as open relative to $Y$. Now you can understand graphically.

Comment: Yes I understood it. Thank you!!

Comment: @NatashaJ You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is open relative to $Y$ means that $E$ is an open set in the metric-space-in-its-own-right $(Y,d)$ where $d$ is the metric from the original metric space $(X,d)$, but just restricted to $Y \times Y$. So when considering open balls in $(Y,d)$ we only have to look at points of $Y$ and we don't "see" the points in $X$ anymore.

E.G. If $X=\Bbb R$ in the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ (the canonical example in analysis) and $Y=[0,1]$, say, then in $(Y,d)$ the open ball around $0$ of radius $\frac12$ is just $[0,\frac12)$ (all points in $Y$ that have distance $<\frac12$ to $0$), which equals $(-\frac12,\frac12) \cap Y$ and so indeed the $Y$-open set $[0,\frac12)$ is the intersection of an $X$-open set with $Y$, just as the theorem claims. This example illustrates the general fact $$B_{Y}(y,r) = B_X(y,r) \cap Y$$ when we take the open balls of radius $r$ in both $X$ and $Y$ around points $y \in Y$, and we see that this relation extends to unions of open balls, i.e. open sets, which is what the theorem says. I don't quite understand what the rest of your question is about. $Y$ open sets are just unions of the balls in $Y$ (which are just the balls in $X$ but with possibly fewer points, namely not those outside of $Y$). It's the exact same notion conceptually as being open in $X$, really.

Comment: Thank you! I will attach a picture of what I'm trying to say. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. English is not my first language.